# FreeBSD with fusefs-s3fs

Tags: freebsd, s3fs

How i can install fusefs-s3fs on FreeBSD OS(example FreeNAS)? I just tried to  install via command:

```
[root@freenas] #pkg install  fusefs-s3fs
```

But it doesn't work and shows the following error:

> pkg: file://usr/ports/pakages/meta.txz: no such file or directory
>   repository local has no meta file,using default settings pkg:
>   file:///usr/ports/packages/packagesite.txz: no such file or directory
>   unable to update repository local all repository upt o date pkg: No
>   packages available to install matching 'fusefs' have been found in
>   repositories

Answer (score 1):

To use pkgng [pkg(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pkg(8)) tool for installing packages in prebuilt binaries, it is better to resolve installation error with pkg, as using pkg is faster and don't require compiler installation.

First, run pkg update with -f to force fetching the repository:

```
pkg update -f
```

To install the package with its dependencies:

```
pkg install fusefs-s3fs
```

You may also use "pkg search" to make sure that the package available  to be installed (fusefs-s3fs is available in my FreeBSD 11.1-R), run:

```
pkg search fusefs-s3fs
```

After installing fusefs-s3fs, load fuse module using:

```
kldload fuse
```

To automatically load fuse moudle on boot, add **fuse_load="YES**" to /boot/loader.conf file.

Note: if you still receive errors when updating packages list using "pkg update -f". Check that you can connect to pkg.FreeBSD.org , and that the pkgng repository config file /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf exists and configured.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have error with your FreeBSD repository. Try to install install using port:

> cd /usr/ports/sysutils/fusefs-s3fs/ && make install clean

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the [port](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/fusefs-s3fs):

```
sudo portsnap fetch extract
cd /usr/ports/sysutils/fusefs-exfat; sudo make install clean
```

Or you can compile it as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse.git
cd s3fs-fuse
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```